# How can I get line numbers be output from css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to write a css stylesheet for use in my wordpress blog, which will output a colored background, highlighted bash code and line-numbers. This is what I've got so far -

```
 code {
     background-color: #FFC0CB;
     list-style-type: decimal;
     border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

But I'm having problems getting highlighted code and also line numbers.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks
Sharon.

Comment: How does your html look like? list-style is something that gives an enumeration of li-Tag enclosed paragraphs a number.

Comment: As its straight bash script, there is no html in it at all. Please see  [link](http://www.sharons.org.uk/2013/07/09/backup-v5-6/) =Backup v5.6 and that post, which shows one of the scripts that I want it to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ynXjz/3/)**

**CSS**

```
 code ul{
list-style-type: decimal;
margin:0;

}
code ul li {
background-color: #FFC0CB;
border-radius: 5px;
margin:3px 0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is what you are trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/BdY2g/

*edit*

http://jsfiddle.net/BdY2g/2/ - new fiddle.
in this new fiddle, i am using javascript to wrap each line in a 'li' tag.
This fiddle requires you to put ID tags on your code in this case: "bashCode" and an onload function that runs the function to update accordingly.

firstly, if you are using classes you need to use a '.' prefix in your css so your

```
code {
```

moves to

```
.code {
```

also, if you use an ordered list (ol) instead of an unordered list (ul) numbering is applied automatically.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes, thats what I would like it to look like, but there wouldn't be any html coding at all in it, its a straight bash script, and this is part of it too -                                                   `[exec] (About) {(fluxbox -v; fluxbox -info | sed 1d) 2> /dev/null | xmessage -file - -center}`
                                                       `[exec] (Arachnophilia web builder) {java -jar ~/programmes/Arachnophilia}`

Comment: Why force the use of a class? `code` is a valid selector for [corresponding HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code).

Comment: Please see the link above of a script that I want it to work on.

Comment: okay, other than having to wrap each line manually i have done this, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/BdY2g/2/